# How to make REST POST calls in R

Tags: r

I have been using jsonlite to make REST GET calls. The number of parameters have increased and I am wondering how to make a REST POST call using R.

Comment: The source of `jsonlite::fromJSON` calls `jsonlite:::download_raw()` which is hard-coded to use the GET method. If you want to use something else, you will need to use `httr::POST` (or an equivalent function) directly to get a string, and call `fromJSON` on that string. Otherwise, please provide more information such as (1) what you are using now, and (2) to what type of service you're connecting.

Comment: To see an example of how you might find this yourself, type in `jsonlite::fromJSON` and notice that when it finds "http" in the provided `txt`, it calls `download_raw(txt)` and then parse the json in it. Since this function is not exported, you'll need the third colon but can read its source too: `jsonlite:::download_raw`, where you see the explicit calls to `httr::GET`.

Comment: httr::POST is probably the way to go. I am new to R. Post your tip as answer so that I can mark it selected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your request ...

```
library(jsonlite)
```

### BLUF

Instead of

```
fromJSON(myurl, ...)
```

you need to call `httr::POST` directly:

```
txt <- httr::POST(myurl, ...)
fromJSON(txt)
```

### Explanation

The basic mechanism for using `jsonlite::fromJSON` is to pass it a string. In the special case that you pass an URL (regexpr: `^https?://`), it does you a courtesy by calling `httr::GET` and taking its output as your intended input. You can see this intent by looking at its source by typing in `jsonlite::fromJSON` and finding the line with `if(grepl("^https?://" ...`; if you try to find the function `download_raw`, you'll not find immediately since it is an un-exported function. You can find it as `jsonlite:::download_raw` (notice the third colon).

Looking at that function's source, you'll see that it makes direct calls to `httr::GET`. You can mimic how `download_raw` is calling `httr::GET`, modifying the arguments as needed. (It might be informative to look at both `help(httr::GET)` and `help(httr::POST)` and look for the differences between them. Spoiler: look at the `body` argument, potentially a list for keys/values. The examples are helpful.)